# combobox dropdown to display several tables from database

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get a combobox dropdown to display tables in datagridview from database, but I don't know how to do it, I can see example and explanation how to display only one table.

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection ();
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.4.0;Data     Source=|DataDirectory|\\Manager.accdb;Persist Security Info=True";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand ("SELECT  Emplyee, Tasks, Projects from Manager");

        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dt, "Manager");  
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem?  Errors?  Is the dataset empty?   Is the datagridview failing to bind?  Or is it you aren't doing anything with the data adapter you filled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no provider named  `"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.4.0;"`, perhaps you want to use `"Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"`

Then, if you want to read all the data from the table names selected in the combobox then your code should be something like this

```
string conString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + 
                   "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Manager.accdb;" + 
                   "Persist Security Info=False";
string tableName = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection (conString))
using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + tableName + "]", conn))
{
    con.Open();
    using(OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds, tableName);  
        dataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

Please, pay attention to the tablenames inserted in your combobox. Having the build of the sql command text made by string concatenation you have a very dangerous situation. Do not let the user inser these names, but select them yourself. If you have a malicious user it could mount an [Sql Injection attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)

Comment: Thank you, but it's not displaying anything, do I have to bind with datagridview?

Comment: What kind of application? WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET. And did you see the names of the tables in the Output Window when debugging?

Comment: And by the way, what are you trying to display?

Comment: I'm trying to display tables from database to datagridview and I wanted to use combobox to select for eg task, instead of using a 4 buttons to display each table.

Comment: OK then you don't need to read the names of the tables. Now I will try to update my answer

Comment: I am back, Thank you Steve for your help, but it doesn't show anything.

Comment: dataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = True ?